# Is the value 0 important in a dataset(too many) for time series analysis anomaly detection?

Tags: python, pandas, anomaly-detection

I am working with a dataset which has variables like temperature and pressure. There are too many 0 values in the dataset as the variables change from positive to negative values frequently. Should I remove the 0 values or do the analysis keeping them?

Comment: What does your data look like? Update your dataframe with a sample.

Comment: Zero is a valid value for temperature to be in, so you should keep them and find an algorithm that can handle zeros properly.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data and explain what kind of analysis you want to perform?